# apacite: suppress initials intext when using apa class

Tags: apa-style

I was able to duplicate Alan's code and made the citations work exactly
as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18954/apacite-suppress-initials-intext).

But, because I am using [man]apa class, it overrides what I have saved to the bapcite file in my local/texmf/bibtex/bst. As a result, my citations still have the extra-initial
issue. Is there a solution for my problem?

Any input will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the `apa` class with the `[noapacite]` option, and then load `apacite` manually with the modified bibliography style.

```
\documentclass[noapacite]{apa}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{bpacite}
```

Comment: @user7375: if Alan's answer helped you, consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count. This will assign reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). `=)`

Comment: @Paulo although in this case it may be appropriate, it's usually a good idea to wait a bit before accepting an answer in case a better answer shows up. (Often people say 24 hrs, but personally, I think it depends on how clear it is that the solution is the optimal one.)

Comment: @Alan: I see. `=)` My bad (it's Sunday, brain doesn't work properly). `=P`

Comment: @AlanMunn Is this a typo? \bibliographystyle{bpacite} in place of \bibliographystyle{apacite}

Comment: @lifezbeautiful No it’s not a typo. This question is about implementing a modified `.bst` which I named `bpacite` for British Psychological Association.

Comment: @AlanMunn got it! Actually this should be read in continuation with this another answer from you as the OP posted initially :) I had missed that  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18982/235554