# Supress initials of authors in biblatex-apa intext

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am referring to exactly the same issue as RSoul in his post a while ago:
[Apacite: suppress initials intext?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18954/apacite-suppress-initials-intext)

However, I am looking for a solution with the biblatex-apa using biber-backend.  It would be great if you could help me with this one!

Just for your convenience, I am citing RSoul with his question as in his post:

> I am writing a doctoral thesis and I am using APAcite to set the
>   references in APA (American Psychological Association) format. Mostly
>   this has worked perfectly fine, but I would like to suppress the
>   author initials from the compiled version (in-text, not in the end
>   references section). This happens because there are multiple authors
>   with the same name e.g.,
>
> Smith and Jones (1992) or Wells and Smith (1901) are typeset in-text
>   as:
>
> I. Smith and Jones (1992) or Wells and D. Smith (1901). Although it
>   may be correct to have the initial in-text in APA format, in reality I
>   am using BPS (British Psychological Society) format, which uses an
>   adapted APA format (and you guessed it, they don't like the initial in
>   text). Thus in-text should look like the first example above (without
>   initial) but looks like the second (with).
>
> To clarify: Any ideas on how to suppress the initial in-text in
>   apacite?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Are you actually using biblatex or just bibtex? Apacite is a bibtex style.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried with the `uniquename=false` option?

```
\usepackage[uniquename=false]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this was caused by two entries in my `.bib` file with authors whose names were specified slightly differently, leaving biblatex (correctly) unsure whether they were really the same person or not.

Specifically, I had:

```
author = {Bruton, Henry},
```

and

```
author = {Bruton, Henry J.},
```

I know enough to know that these "two" authors are really one and the same, but it would be bad for biblatex to make the same assumption. Thus, the first citation appeared as `Bruton (1989)` and the second as `HJ Bruton (1998)` as biblatex sought to differentiate the two Brutons.

@Guido's solution works by instructing biblatex to give up on trying to uniquify names. There's some discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162212/initials-in-the-bibliography-firstinits-uniquename-not-working-correctly-in-bib) of other options if you don't want such a brute force method.