# \DeclareLabelname not working in biblatex 3.0

Tags: biblatex, biber

I recently upgraded to TeX Live 2015 and `biblatex` version 3.0. Since the upgrade, there is unexpected behavior with respect to my in-text author-year citations.

As I describe in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202831/42880), I reserve the `author` field in my `.bib` entries for the author's name as formatted in the actual source. To unify authors who have published under various permutations of their name (authority control), I use the `sortname` field in my `.bib` entries and the use `\DeclareLabelname` to put `sortname` before `author` in the list of fields stored in `labelname`. With `biblatex` 2.9a, this allowed in-text citations to be grouped by `sortname` rather than `author`.

### MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{dembetembe1974,
    title = {Three {Korekore} dialects},
    volume = {15},
    pages = {143--172},
    journaltitle = {Journal of African Languages},
    author = {Dembetembe, Norris C.},
    date = {1974}
}
@thesis{dembetembe1976,
    location = {London},
    title = {The syntax of sentential complements in {Shona}},
    institution = {University of London},
    type = {phdthesis},
    author = {Dembetembe, Norris Clemens},
    sortname = {Dembetembe, Norris C.},
    date = {1976}
}
@article{dembetembe1986,
    title = {Aspects of negation in {Shona}},
    volume = {6},
    pages = {1--10},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {South African Journal of African Languages},
    author = {Dembetembe, N. C.},
    sortname = {Dembetembe, Norris C.},
    date = {1986}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
    dashed=false, % no dash in bibliography
    uniquename=init, % we can still disambiguate names in citations
    firstinits=false, % full names are used in bibliography
    backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelname{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{shortauthor}
    \field{author}
    \field{shorteditor}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\parencite{dembetembe1974,dembetembe1976,dembetembe1986}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

### Intended Output (worked with `biblatex` 2.9a)

[image]

However, with `biblatex` 3.0, for `.bib` entries where there is a `sortname` field, none of the fields that should be in `labelname` according to my `\DeclareLabelname` command are being used in the in-text citation. Instead, the `title` field is being used. Perhaps `labelname` is being resolved as undefined and so `labeltitle` is being used in its place?

### Actual Output with `biblatex` 3.0

[image]

I see in the `biblatex` changelog that version 3.0 moved the resolution of `labelname` and `labeltitle` from `biber` to `biblatex`, and I assume that this is the source of the change in my output, but I'm not sure how to get the intended behavior back.

Comment: It indeed seems like the `labelname` is not generated for those entries that feature a `sortname`. That is probably worth a bug report at the [`biblatex` bug tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues).

Comment: @moewe, thanks. I submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/329).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting case. Before biber 2.0/biblatex 3.0 labelname was, as you say, generated by biber but is now instantiated by biblatex. Biber doesn't pass sortname back out in the .bbl as it's only used for sorting and biblatex shouldn't need it. Therefore, this shouldn't really ever have worked but it did because biber had access to sortname while it was processing labelname generation. Really, this should be done using a user field like `namea`. Try this:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource=sortname]
       \step[fieldset=namea, origfieldval, final]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareLabelname{
    \field{namea}
    \field{shortauthor}
    \field{author}
    \field{shorteditor}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
}
```