# Apacite: first initial removal in-text in Overleaf when two authors have the same family name

Tags: bibliographies, citing, overleaf, apacite

I'm writing my thesis in Overleaf, using the `apacite` package. The problem I encounter is that different authors with the same family name get their first-name initials shown in citation call-outs, obviously to distinguish between them.

I found this: [Apacite: suppress initials intext?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18954/apacite-suppress-initials-intext?newreg=35525c1cd1454ca9ae37138a5c214702) but it doesn't help me on how to change this in Overleaf. Any idea how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious: Under what circumstances do you not wish to distinguish between two different persons?

Comment: @pst It's only in true corner cases where both the year of publication and the last name are the same that are likely critical. And even in that case, unless the two cited papers are almost identical, context would likely distinguish them too in many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer solution will work on Overleaf. Download a copy of `apacite.dtx` and `apacite.ins` into your Overleaf project folder from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite).

Then put the following as the first line of your document (you only need to do this once):

```
\immediate\write18{latex apacite.ins}
```

This will create a copy of `apacite.bst` in your project folder. Unfortunately it will be placed in the same directory as your log files and other files. If you select that file from the list in the "Other Logs and Files" menu  you can download it to your computer and then re-upload it to your main project directory. I'm not sure if there is a way to do this directly.

I would rename it as advised in the linked answer. You can delete the `.dtx` and `.ins` files and the line above once you have successfully created the copy of `apacite.bst`.

Comment: As you said, I added \immediate\write18{latex apacite.ins} as the first line in the document, but it doesn't create a copy of apacite.bst to my project folder.

Comment: @mathijshast Sorry, I forgot that the file gets placed in the Other Logs and Files folder, which means it's not directly editable. So you need to download the generated file from there and then upload it back to your main directory to edit.

Comment: That indeed fixed the complete issue. Thank you very much!