# Omit Initials in citation with APA style

Tags: citing, apa-style, multiple-citations

I have read multiple Q&A here where they referred `uniquename=false` as a solution to get rid of initials in case of same surname. But it is also mentioned that in such case APA style is suspected. I want to know about the solution with APA style and without initials in citations.
I am using:

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

**For Example**
I have `\citet{jones1995kernel} said....` which become `W.M. Jones (1995) said....` . Actually, I want `Jones (1995) said ....`

Comment: If I understand correctly (there is always a risk I might not, if there is no example to reproduce what you are asking about) the added initial is required by APA style. I don't think `apacite` lets you disable that feature easily (it could be disabled by modifying the `.bst` file, which can be quite painful). (`uniquename=false,` would be the `biblatex` solution.)

Comment: @moewe i don't want to disable the initials in References. I want to get rid of initials in citation., which appear when there is more than one reference with same surname. check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18954/apacite-suppress-initials-intext but its very complicated for me.

Comment: @JAK - What's so complicated about [Alan Munn's suggested solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18982/5001)? All it requires is to (a) create a modified form of the `apacite.bst` file, where the modificaton consists of reducing a single BibTeX function to a stub, and (b) change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` from `apacite` to `bpacite`. If there's a specific step you're unsure about, please let us know so that we may help.

Comment: Initials in citations are required by APA style to disambiguate authors with the same family name. The initials in the references do not come into this. But as I said: This will involve modifying the `.bst` file. As Alan's answer shows it is not actually that bad, but I can understand that it looks daunting. It's the only way, though.

Comment: @Mico I m confuses about how to make modifications.... e.g. how to open .bst file? How to open terminal window? etc

Comment: @JAK - Please start by telling us which operating system (Windows? MacOS? Something else?) and which TeX distribution (MikTeX? TeXLive? MacTeX? Something else?) you employ. Or do you employ Overleaf? Please be specific?

Comment: windows 10, Miktex